# Clearing data from Apache Nutch

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am just starting out with Apache Nutch and I have been following some tutorials which I have been succesful with. I would now like to delete all of the data that was collected while I've been playing around, is there a way to easily clear all downloaded data from Nutch?

Answer (score 1):

Purely from the Nutch side deleting all the segments (usually within the `crawldb` directory) should get you back into a clean slate. If you've been indexing data into Solr/ES/etc., you might want to (potentially) remove all that data as well. This last step might depend on which storage engine you're using.